# Scanned document prints with a blue background from Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, scanning

I have scanned a document, and now I need to print it. The document has both black and blue on it. However, it has a white background. When I print it from Photoshop it prints with a light blue background, instead of white. Anybody knows what to do in order to remove that? So again, it's a white background on the original paper and in Photoshop, but when print it comes out with a light blue background.

Comment: You should insert a piece of the scanned document to the question; crop a scanned page to remove sensitive information or paint on it some black but leave all different colors in the image. Give some info of your printer and insert a screenshot of the printing dialog. Does pure BW image come out OK?

Comment: Printer is Canon Pixma MG2550S. Windows 10. Photoshop CS6. I have seen a similar post and it had to do with Photoshop image mode, RGB or CMYK. I tried that but it prints out the same. Nothing to see on the document, it's just a regular document only that the printed background is light blue instead of white

Comment: You didn't show the printing dialog in Photoshop. You didn't bother to tell how is treated a sRGB document which has pure black and white, checked with the color picker that white is RGB 255,255,255 and black is RGB 0,0,0. Do not expect anything useful without giving anything essential data. A scanned image can have some obscure scanner specific color profile and that can be bypassed in printing by a randomly operating user. Greys can get a substantial color cast.

Comment: OK, I got this. I checked the background color with the color picker and it is light blue :((( it really light, it doesn't show on the screen. Is it because of it being scanned? Is there a way I can scan it with a white background and still keep the other colors? The document itself has a white background... I don't see how it was turned into blue through scanning

Comment: I sorted it out. I adjusted the levels from Photoshop... and now it's ok. Thank you!

Comment: Comments are often written to get some data beyond guessing. In this case you found the track, maybe after a kick given by an intrusive comment. I see own solutions worth pursuing. Accept your own answer to close the case.

Comment: I will, but it only allows me to close it after 2 days...

Comment: no, problem. Accepting makes the case visible as solved and can be found by those who search working solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was sorted out as it follows: indeed, because it was scanned as a photo, the document inherited a light blue background. I edited that in Photoshop by adjusting Image->Adjustments->Levels, I picked the color from the background and it turned it into white automatically